# What is the proper way to deal with non-unique rows that will become unique

Tags: sql

I'm building a database for archery tournament shoots.
One of the tables holds the work shifts for the volunteers working it.

It currently looks like this:

```
+-------+---------+--------+---------+-------+-----+
| JobID | ShiftID | UserID | EventID | Hours | Day |
+-------+---------+--------+---------+-------+-----+
|    10 |       9 |   1125 |       6 | NULL  |   1 |
|    11 |       9 |      0 |       6 | NULL  |   1 |
+-------+---------+--------+---------+-------+-----+
```

JobID links to the jobs i.e. registration, kitchen.

ShiftID links to the hours of the shift i.e. 7-9 (hours is there at the request of the event owner as a shift may run long).

UserID links to the volunteer...

EventID links to the specific event.

Day is day of the event, for events that span multiple days.

The entries are populated for the events, and then users are added.
This currently allows for a unique constraint to be placed on the concatenated columns (JobID, ShiftID, UserID, EventID).

However, the event owner now wants to be able to have multiple shifts in an event at the same time. The entries will be unique after the user has been registered.

What would be the proper way to deal with this?
These were the solutions that I thought of, but none of them felt right:

1. Making a new shift.
2. Making a new job.
3. Making a new table for pending jobshifts.
4. Removing the unique constraint on the table.
5. Adding another column to deal with the duplicate shifts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your concern is with the constraints.

One method of fitting the multiple shifts into the current schema is to "invent" place-holder users.  If you only needed to support two shifts at the same time, you can just set the `user` to NULL and the constraint is ok.  For more than two shifts, create new user ids -- perhaps with negative ids so they are obvious -- that really mean "there is no user for this shift yet".

Comment: I like this idea.
Is this a common problem, or have i done something weird to encounter this?